# Making a vector with string elements

Tags: r, vector

I want to make the following vector with string elements:

```r
L1  L1  L2  L2  L3  L3  L4  L4  L5  L5  L6  L6  L7  L7  L8  L8  L9  L9  L10  L10
```

To make this vector, I used the below code:

```r
rep(c("L1","L1","L2","L2","L3","L3","L4","L4"),2)
```

But I think there is a shorter (easier or simpler) code than my code. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
paste0("L", rep(1:10, each = 2))

 [1] "L1"  "L1"  "L2"  "L2"  "L3"  "L3"  "L4"  "L4"  "L5"  "L5"  "L6"  "L6"  "L7" 
[14] "L7"  "L8"  "L8"  "L9"  "L9"  "L10" "L10"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
paste0("L", sort(rep(c(1:10), 2)))

 [1] "L1"  "L1"  "L2"  "L2"  "L3"  "L3"  "L4"  "L4"  "L5"  "L5"  "L6"  "L6" 
[13] "L7"  "L7"  "L8"  "L8"  "L9"  "L9"  "L10" "L10"
```

The idea here is to use `rep` to generate the sequence 1:10 twice.  Then, we sort ascending to force 1, 1, 2, 2, ..., 10, 10.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `rbind` and `paste`

```
paste0("L", rbind(1:10, 1:10))
#[1] "L1"  "L1"  "L2"  "L2"  "L3"  "L3"  "L4"  "L4"  "L5"  "L5"  "L6"  "L6"  "L7"  "L7"  "L8"  "L8"  "L9"  "L9"  "L10" "L10"
```

---

Or with `replicate`

```
paste0("L", t(replicate(2, 1:10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
rep(paste0("L", 1:10), each=2)
#>  [1] "L1"  "L1"  "L2"  "L2"  "L3"  "L3"  "L4"  "L4"  "L5"  "L5"  "L6"  "L6" 
#> [13] "L7"  "L7"  "L8"  "L8"  "L9"  "L9"  "L10" "L10"
```